# Disabling an input field of a MatFormField in Angular

Tags: angular, forms, typescript

I know there has been similar questions about this topic but none of them worked for me since the solutions depend on either `AngularJS` or `JQuery`.

In `Angular 5`, I'm trying to disable the `<input>` of a `<mat-form-field>`:

> test.component.html

```
<mat-form-field class="example-form">
  <input matInput disabled [matDatepicker]="picker" [value]="startDate || ab.value" placeholder="Gültig ab" [formControl]="ab">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker disabled="false" ></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

But this doesn't work at all. I even tried to set `disabled=true` but this didn't get the job done. Additionally, I can't disable any of the other form fields in my component.

This is how my `TypeScript` file looks like:

> test.component.ts

```
import ...

@Component({ ... })

export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
// A Couple of @Input statements
@Input() ...

// Create Formcontrollers
 controlNumber = new FormControl("", [Validators.pattern("[0-9]*")]);
 controlText = new FormControl("", [Validators.pattern("[A-Z-a-z]*")]);
 datePicker = new FormControl(moment());


 constructor(private http: HttpClient) {  }

 ngOnInit() {
 }

 ...

 getNotANumberMessage() {
  return this.controlNumber .hasError("pattern") ? "Numbers only" : "";
 }

 getNotAStringMessage() {
   return this.controlText.hasError("pattern") ? "Strings only" : "";
 }
 }
```

What am I missing?

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a formcontroller for `ab` (your input) and set the disable property true.

```
ab = new FormControl("", [ Validators.pattern("[A-Z-a-z]*"), disabled:true ]);
```

Comment: You meant this, right? 

`ab = new FormControl({value: "", disabled: true}, Validators.pattern("[A-Za-z]*"));` 
See the [Official Documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#initializing-form-controls) for further information